# C# replace the selection of regex by another selection of regex if a condition is met

Tags: c#, regex

I am parsing some html code and what I am trying is to replace alt in img by its src value(without suffix) if and only if the alt is empty.

Example:

Input:

```
... some HTML here ....
<img src="my_image.jpg" alt="something_is_already_here" width="450" height="300">
... some HTML here ....
<img src="my_image2.jpg" alt="" width="450" height="300"
```

Output:

```
... some HTML here ....
<img src="my_image.jpg" alt="something_is_already_here" width="450" height="300">
... some HTML here ....
<img src="my_image2.jpg" alt="my_image2" width="450" height="300">
```

I've already written the regular expressions for src and alt, but don't know how to use it to do what I exactly need.

```
//src=\"([^"]*)\.jpg\"
string srcPattern = "src=\\\"([^\"]*)\\.jpg\\\"";
//alt=\"([^"]*)\"
string altPattern = "alt=\\\"([^\"]*)\\\"";
Regex rSrc = new Regex(srcPattern);
Regex rAlt = new Regex(altPattern);
```

Comment: What `img` tags should be affected (the first one is not, why only the second one is)? Why do you rely on regex for HTML parsing? Use HtmlAgilityPack, or any other HTML parser.

Comment: @stribizhev The first one is not affected cause the value of alt is not empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with HTML parser ([HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - install as a NuGet Package): you can pass either a URL or an HTML string to the `HtmlAgilityPackPopulateAltWithSrcIfEmpty` method, and the output will be the HTML string with populated alts in img tags.

The XPath used `//img[string-length(@alt) = 0]` selects all `img` tags (`//img`) whose `alt` attribute value is empty (`[string-length(@alt) = 0]`).

The `alt` is only populated with part of `src` if `src` value ends with `.jpg` extension. Then, only the part before the extension is used to set the `alt` attribute.

```
public string HtmlAgilityPackPopulateAltWithSrcIfEmpty(string html)
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hap;
        Uri uriResult;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(html, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
        { // html is a URL 
            var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            hap = doc.Load(uriResult.AbsoluteUri);
        }
        else
        { // html is a string
            hap = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            hap.LoadHtml(html);
        }
        var nodes = hap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[string-length(@alt) = 0]");
        if (nodes != null)
        {
            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                var val = node.GetAttributeValue("src", string.Empty);
                if (val.ToUpper().EndsWith(".JPG"))
                    node.SetAttributeValue("alt", val.Substring(0, val.Length - 4));
            }
        }
        var ffg = hap.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
        return hap.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
    }
```

Use it like:

```
var s = "<img src=\"my_image.jpg\" alt=\"something_is_already_here\" width=\"450\" height=\"300\"><img src=\"my_image2.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"450\" height=\"300\">";
var new_html = HtmlAgilityPackPopulateAltWithSrcIfEmpty(s);
```

Result:

`<img src="my_image.jpg" alt="something_is_already_here" width="450" height="300"><img src="my_image2.jpg" alt="my_image2" width="450" height="300">`

Comment: I agree that is probably better to use the Agilitypack because otherwise the code looks really bad.

Comment: Otherwise, you will have to account for many other things than alt and src values. Let the parser do the "dirty" work for you, you focus on what you really need to achieve when you get the correct node. Regex in this case will cause you much pain and maintenance will be next to impossible.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a Regex.Replace.
As you want to replace a different regex on your find, you need to use a if.

First you need to filter out the whole line with the img-Tag as you want to replace its source and not of any src ;)

To filter using regex use Regex.IsMatch(text, pattern).

Example:

```
string text = Console.ReadLine();
string reg = @"^((([\w]+\.[\w]+)+)|([\w]+))@(([\w]+\.)+)([A-Za-z]{1,3})$";

if (Regex.IsMatch(text, reg))
{
     Console.WriteLine("Email."); 
}
```

You make a pattern for the img-Tag line and then you go further by IsMatch(imgLine, patternForAlt) and check if it is empty, if yes you use the Replace(srcTag, replacetext).

If you try this and provide code with your try if it's not working, I can help you further.

## Edit

You can use https://regex101.com/ to test your regex easily before using it in the program :)